# Fetch data from xml using ElementTree in Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to extract some data from a xml file. Given below is how the xml looks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Stores>
  <Store>
<Action>new</Action>
<StoreID>1001</StoreID>
<EmpID/>
<Agent>
  <Name/>
  <EmpName>Scott</EmpName>
</Name>
<BillData>
  <BillInfo>
    <Action>new</Action>
    <CustName></CustName>
    <BillNumber>3343</BillNumber>
   </BillInfo>
  </BillData>
 </Store>
</Stores>
```

I am trying to fetch each of the columns along with its data from the above dataset. Given below is what I have achieved thus far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
    for elem in root:
        for subelem in elem:
        print(subelem.tag)
        print(subelem.text)
```

Output is as below:

```
Action
new
StoreID
1001
Agent


BillData
```

I am trying to extract data that is at the child level. Could anyone advice how could I extract data stored under 'BillInfo' namely

```
Action
new
CustName
BillNumber
3343
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple recursive function that achieves what you want :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
search(root)

def search(elem):
    for e in elem:
        print(e.tag)
        print(e.text)
        search(e)
```

Comment: thanks that helped.. Could you please help me have the view changed such that tag is the header and we have the corresponding text under that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to recursively iterate over all elements in the XML tree, you should use the [iter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.iter) method. Something like the following should get you want you want:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
for elem in tree.iter():
    print(elem.tag)
    print(elem.text)
```

Comment: thanks that helped.. Could you please assist me on how I could have the tag added to a column and have the text under that..